# Delete logs after consumption: logstash

Tags: linux, logging, distributed-computing

I have logstash watching a directory on the host.  Every time it sees a log that matches the path I specified in the logstash config it starts to import the data into my elasticsearch cluster.  Does logstash have a way to delete the log after it is done consuming it?  As is I have to write scripts to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no it doesn't. There doesn't seem to be a feature request for this either, so maybe you can submit one?